# Why 'grib2json' is not recognized as an internal or external command while i already installed it?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I m working on `earth.null.school` github code to implement it locally in my window 10 system. But i am facing this issue.

[github code](https://github.com/cambecc/earth) - Code i am using.

[demo](https://earth.nullschool.net/) - Demo of the code.

I have grib2json node module present but still the window command prompt is not working. I am trying the below command in window 10 command prompt. I am using this to convert the temperature file to json file using `grib2json` node library.

Of the above github code i am trying the below window cmd command.

```
>>> curl "http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs.pl?file=gfs.t00z.pgrb2.1p00.f000&lev_10_m_above_ground=on&var_UGRD=on&var_VGRD=on&dir=%2Fgfs.${YYYYMMDD}00" -o gfs.t00z.pgrb2.1p00.f000
>>> grib2json -d -n -o current-wind-surface-level-gfs-1.0.json gfs.t00z.pgrb2.1p00.f000
```

path for the `grib2json` is `\Desktop\earth\node_modules\grib2json`.
and code file are there in `earth`.

```
C:\Users\Desktop\earth>grib2json -d -n -o current-wind-surface-level-gfs-1.0.json gfs.t00z.pgrb2.1p00.f000
'grib2json' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I also tried the globally node modules as suggested in comment section, again nothing happened.

```
C:\Users\Desktop\earth>npm i -grib2json
audited 382 packages in 3.024s
found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

C:\Users\Desktop\earth>grib2json -d -n -o current-wind-surface-level-gfs-1.0.json gfs.t00z.pgrb2.1p00.f000
'grib2json' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Same thing happening again.

```
C:\Users\Carthaginian\Desktop\earth>npm install -g grib2json
+ grib2json@1.0.2
added 3 packages from 2 contributors in 2.4s

C:\Users\Carthaginian\Desktop\earth>grib2json -d -n -o current-wind-surface-level-gfs-1.0.json gfs.t00z.pgrb2.1p00.f000
'grib2json' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Try installing the package globally in case you want to use it from anywhere (npm i -g ...). If you don't want to install it globally, have a look at npx module - https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx.

Comment: @RvyPandey still facing problem of no use, i tried what you suggested.

Comment: Your global install command is incorrect. Check again. It would be `npm install -g grib2json`.

Comment: @Dijkstra same thing happening again

Comment: Try this, from your terminal you cd in this directory `\Desktop\earth\node_modules\grib2json` then run the  command.

Comment: @Dijkstra same thing happening `\Desktop\earth\node_modules\grib2json>grib2json -d -n -o current-wind-surface-level-gfs-1.0.json gfs.t00z.pgrb2.1p00.f000
'grib2json' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution - https://github.com/cambecc/grib2json, please find below commands and result in windows 10 cmd prompt.

```
C:\Users\Desktop\earth>git clone https://github.com/cambecc/grib2json.git
Cloning into 'grib2json'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 322, done.
                                                                Receiving objects:  74% (239/322), 28.01 KiBReceiving objects:  77% (248/322), 28.01 KiB | 41.00 KiB/s
Receiving objects: 100% (322/322), 52.70 KiB | 88.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (105/105), done.

C:\Users\Desktop\earth>grib2json
'grib2json' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Desktop\earth>cd grib2json

C:\Users\Desktop\earth\grib2json>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< net.nullschool:grib2json >----------------------
[INFO] Building grib2json 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom (8.1 kB at 1.8 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/23/maven-plugins-23.pom
|
|
|
|
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.2/plexus-compiler-javac-2.2.pom (769 B at 678 B/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compilers/2.2/plexus-compilers-2.2.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compilers/2.2/plexus-compilers-2.2.pom (1.2 kB at 917 B/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.5.5/plexus-container-default-1.5.5.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.5.5/plexus-container-default-1.5.5.pom (2.8 kB at 613 B/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.4.5/plexus-utils-1.4.5.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.4.5/plexus-utils-1.4.5.pom (2.3 kB at 1.5 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/2.2.2/plexus-classworlds-2.2.2.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/2.2.2/plexus-classworlds-2.2.2.pom (4.0 kB at 4.4 kB/s)
|
|
|
|
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/assembly/assembly.xml
[INFO] Building tar: C:\Users\Desktop\earth\grib2json\target\grib2json-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  24:38 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-04T14:34:13+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after I try the above method. Then I go to `your drive\...\grib2json\src\bin` open cmd (I'm using Windows), when I open the directory `\src\bin` on cmd I could use the command such as `grib2json --help`.

I mean to use the tools, u have to open in a specific directory `...\...\grib2json\src\bin`. I hope this help peoples.

For me the next problem is to fit the coordinate convert from grib2 to json. I try to reduce digit from converted coordinate exmpl `-1,293029` to `-1,29` using excel and it works! Well at hourly cost of time to learn thats all from `grib2json` and fitting coordinate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).